# Mimic Jquery ui Tab change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

So, time for my first question after years of reading SO questions and answers. This one I think is tricky:

I have a page with Jquery ui Tabs. The first tab content is a large table with quite a lot of functions attached to the table elements. The other tabs have content not relevant for this question, mostly text.

**What I want:** Click on second Tab changes some properties of the content of first Tab and second Tab get "active state" (and first tab of course "inactive"). The second tab is actually empty and content is still showing first tab contents (with some alterations).

**Why?** I have tried cloning the first tab content and inserting it on second tab which is working but, because of the size and many functions I guess, very slooow. Initial loading is also slow and I don't want to load a second version and double initial loading time.

**What I have tried:** I have tried manipulating tab properties on the "beforeActivate" event which is partally working: With the code below: Clicking second tab makes it active but after that, first tab is not responding to clicks until another tab is chosen.

```
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.newTab.index() == 1){
            event.preventDefault();
            var activeobj = $( ".ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active" );
            activeobj.prop('tabindex', '-1');
            activeobj.prop('aria-selected', 'false');//not sure if the aria properties really needs changing
            activeobj.prop('aria-expanded', 'false');
            ui.oldTab.removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');

            ui.newTab.addClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
            var newactiveobj = $( ".ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active" );
            newactiveobj.prop('tabindex', '0');
            newactiveobj.prop('aria-selected', 'true');
            newactiveobj.prop('aria-expanded', 'true');
        }
        else if(ui.oldTab.index() == 1){
            var activeobj = $( ".ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active" );
            activeobj.prop('tabindex', '-1');
            activeobj.prop('aria-selected', 'false');
            activeobj.prop('aria-expanded', 'false');
            ui.oldTab.removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
            if(ui.newTab.index() == 0){
                event.preventDefault();
                ui.newTab.addClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
                var newactiveobj = $( ".ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active" );
                newactiveobj.prop('tabindex', '0');
                newactiveobj.prop('aria-selected', 'true');
                newactiveobj.prop('aria-expanded', 'true');
            }
        }
    }
```

Next problem would be if second tab is clicked, coming from higher tabs. In this case Tab 1 content is to be shown, but Tab 2 marked as active....
My head is spinning after spending hours with this, and I will probably have to give this up, but it would be a nice hack. If I'm lucky there are some (a lot of?) guys smarter than me out there. Other approaches are also welcome...

Link to fiddle for anyone interested to try: http://jsfiddle.net/moonworker/qnna248z/3/

The fiddle has content on the second tab just for illustration, In the real case it is empty.

First Tab: Pink content, Second Tab: White content, Third Tab: Yellow content

Comment: OMG! Just got it! Soo easy. Just make the markup for tab 2 refer to the div for tab 1, and skip completely the div for tab2. Haha, anyone have a better solution? Updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/moonworker/qnna248z/6